# git stash `No local changes` but git status `ahead of origin/master by 3 commits`

Tags: git

I did a `git commit -am` followed immediately by `git stash` and got the message
    `No local changes to save`

When I run `git status` I get
    `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.`

Is this right?

I was working on some stuff and made some commits but haven't pushed the changes. Now I want to 'stash' them and go back to a clean version (my latest `pushed` changes - don't know how to refer to this)

How do I stash my work that I haven't pushed yet and revert to the latest pushed master branch?

Comment: It is right, you are tree commits ahead, not behind. What do you mean saying `How do I stash my work and go to the master`? Are you not in the `master` branch? Show the output `git branch`

Comment: What are you asking? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I think what you've done is confused branches and stashes.  You want to put your local changes in the stash.  If you want to go back to where origin/master is while saving your work, you can `git checkout origin/master`.  You can also push your commits to master with `git push origin master` or you can save your work in a new branch, then check out origin/master.

Comment: @Andy, yes you are right, I thought `git stash` would stash committed changes that weren't pushed yet. I need to remove the commits and then stash?

Comment: @zaratustra Thanks, I updated my question. I am trying to save my work and start clean. I have run `git commit` but not `git push`

Comment: The key question is do you really want to "save" your current work? Or are you happy to lose it and get your latest pushed changes?

Comment: @codemonkey I want to save it in case I need to go back to it.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859486/un-commit-last-un-pushed-git-commit-without-losing-the-changes which explains how to do a soft reset, which is what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. What I did was
`git reset --soft origin/master
 git stash save 'stashing my unfinished changes'`

This undid all my commits but left all my changed files. I was then able to stash the changes since they weren't committed yet. It automatically reset my local files to origin/master after I stashed.

Answer (score 17):

If I understand if right, you need:

1) Save your local changes.

```
git add -A
git stash
```

2) Backup your commits

```
git branch my_master_backup
```

3) Reset your HEAD back to origin/master

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

4) Do some work that you want to to with the "clean version"

5) Restore changes that you have made with your commits. Fix conflicts if any.

```
git merge my_master_backup
```

6) Drop the backup branch. If you can't delete it means that you haven't fully merged your backup branch and the master.

```
git branch -d my_master_backup
```

6) Restore your local changes from the step 1:

```
git stash pop
```

PS: you can avoid creating a backup branch and use [reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). When you want to restore your commits you need to execute `git merge HEAD@{X}` where X is the number of the desired commit from reflog.

Comment: I don't believe the OP has anything to actually stash.  And he wants to retain his work, so a hard reset wouldn't give him what he wants.

Comment: I suggested the OP to stash their local (uncommited) changes and make a backup branch before hard reseting. So those changes/commits will always be available to them.

Answer (score 1):

From your question and the comments, it sounds like what you want to do is go **back** to the remote repository's master branch commit, *but retain the changes you have made since you have done this*.

What you can do is just create a new local branch where the remote (assuming it is called `origin`) branch is (assuming you are working with `master`).

```
$ git checkout -b original-master origin/master
```

This will create a new branch called `original-master` (and check out this branch, bringing your working directory back to where `origin/master` is pointing to) that will be at the same commit as the remote `origin`'s `master` branch.

At this point, the 3 commits you have from `origin/master` to (local) `master` will be preserved, but you can start a different branch of development with a parent of `origin/master` (by having a new branch called `original-master`).

Comment: I find it a little confusing, because the remote master now tracks two different local branches (`master` and `original-master`)

Comment: @zaratustra The OP is looking to preserve his changes on his local `master` branch.  Without having these commits "orphaned" I don't see any way around that.  As for the naming, OP can change the names of the branches if he so chooses.

Comment: Good idea, let's see which solution fits better:)