# How to delete a commit and get back changes in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, git-commit

I did a commit in Android Studio but I want to make more changes but I also don't want to do another commit.

I can see my commit here [image]

What I want to do, is to get back my changes here and delete this commit without pushing it to Github.

[image]

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to un-commit last un-pushed git commit without losing the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859486/how-to-un-commit-last-un-pushed-git-commit-without-losing-the-changes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

get the desired commit hash by using on the BRANCH_NAME which contains the commit you want :

```
git log
```

copy the hash and use this command

```
git checkout COMMIT_HASH
```

then will generate a temp branch, to save it you can use

```
git switch -c NEW_BRANCH_NAME
```

to rollback your old branch to this commit run the following two commands

```
git checkout BRANCH_NAME
git merge NEW_BRANCH_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```