# Git - Same User, Different Machine - Clone?

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm new to Git and I searched for an answer to this but couldn't quite find what I need.

Basically, I have setup a project on my work computer, added files etc and commited to a GitHub repository. I get all that but once I got home, I wanted to download that same project and change a few files as the same user.

At home, I've set up my user.name and user.email like so:

```
git config --global user.name "username"
git config --global user.email "email"
```

What I think I do next is:

```
git clone url
```

As I said, I'm the same user just working from a different computer - is there anything special I need to do to make sure Git recognises that I'm the same user?

I'm aware this is probably a silly question but nowhere I've found seems to cover this and I really want to make 100% sure that I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I push to GitHub under a different username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103083/how-do-i-push-to-github-under-a-different-username)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Anything else? Nope. Configuring Git with the same email address on both machines should do the trick since commits are [associated to the committer's email address](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Identity). You might have a little more work cut out for you if you're using GPG for [signing tags](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging#Signed-Tags), but that isn't in your question.

The other answer's mention of setting up an [SSH key on Github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) isn't required for maintaining identity across machines — but not needing to type in your password will certainly make life easier. You can also use the Git credential helper to [cache your Github password](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching).

If you're working on Git projects across multiple machines, you might also want to add [Dropbox into your workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961515/1084401) for even more power.

Answer (score 2):

That should work just fine.  You may need to [set up a public SSH key](https://github.com/settings/ssh) for github, especially if you don't want to have to type in your password every time you push to github.

Answer (score 1):

(as of 2022) GitHub has deprecated the use of signing in with your username and password from the command line. They now offer the seamless [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/README.md) that lets you login from the GitHub website whenever your CLI `git` tries to verify your GitHub user credentials.

You can install with Homebrew:

```bash
brew tap microsoft/git
brew install --cask git-credential-manager-core
```

or by downloading the [install .pkg](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/latest).