# git: same user multiple client hosts, cannot get working

Tags: git, ssh, key, config, clone

I was using git on my office workstation. Then for the Covid lockdown I started using it on my home PC. Now when I try to clone on my office workstation I get the error: Permission denied (publickey).

It seems like the git configuration I did on my home PC overwrote the key for my office workstation. I need to be able to use both client hosts, so I don't want to do another config on my office and then not be able to use git as the same user on my home PC.

According to this post:

[Git - Same User, Different Machine - Clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151088/git-same-user-different-machine-clone)

I should be able to just issue git config on both client hosts and both should work, but that's not true based on my experience.

What am I missing?

Comment: You probably have different ssh keys on both machines. I assume you are pushing to github or some online server? You need to add both of your pub keys to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The `git config user.name/email` is only about commit authorship, not authentication.

You should create a key dedicated to your home PC (you can replace `~` with `%USERPROFILE%` if you are on Windows):

```
ssh-keygen -P "" -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/homegh
```

And use a config file: `~/.ssh/config` (there, you can keep `~`)

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/homegh
```

Finally, test if the public key has been properly registered to your account with

```
ssh -tv gh
```

And clone your repository:

```
git clone gh:<me>/<myRepo>
```