# How to specify multiple user.name and user.email for different git remotes?

Tags: git

I have a repository in my local machine. This repository has 2 git remotes. Remotes A and B.

- Remote **A** requires `user.name` **X** and `user.email` **Y**.
- Remote **B** requires `user.name` **Z** and `user.email` **W**.

Can this be achieved in git? If so, how?

Comment: Make two repositories for the two remotes. Config `user.name` and `user.email` with `git config --local` in each repository. `user.name` and `user.email` have nothing to do with a remote.

Comment: how about you have different username and email of your bitbucket and github accounts? you can't use them both at the same time as remote repositories?

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` have nothing with remotes. They are only used to put commiter's name/email in commits, that's all. If you want to have different authorization for different remotes you can create different ssh keys and configure ssh to use each key for a different remote host.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push to GitHub under a different username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103083/how-do-i-push-to-github-under-a-different-username)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.13, you now have [conditional include for `git config`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621480/6309), but it is only based on filesystem path of the repository.

So you still need two different copies of the same repo. You can achieve that [with `git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) (one clone, multiple working tree)

You can then modify your *global*  config spec to include a local config with a specific set of user.name/user.email depending on your current folder.
See "[Using different Git emails](http://pliutau.com/using-different-git-emails/)" from [`pltvs`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350294/pltvs) ([Alex Pliutau](https://twitter.com/pliutau))

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce everybody to a typical scenario:

Bob is a developer with a personal github user attached to his personal email address. Bob has a private dotfiles repository hosted on github.com. Bob gets a job at Acme corp and wants to share his dotfiles with coworkers. Bob uses his employer provisioned username and email to create a public dotfiles repository on an enterprise gitlab server only accessible from the corporate network at Acme Corp.

In this scenario the proper way to interact with these repositories is to configure your global git config on your work machine to use your work user.name and user.email:

- `git config --global user.name <work-username>`
- `git config --global user.email <work-email>`
- On the work machine create a new key that can be used to access your public github:

  - `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your-github-username:GITHUB" -f ~/.ssh/your-github-username`*
- Login to public github account in browser and add the newly created public key to your account (found at `~/.ssh/your-github-username.pub`)
- From work machine run:

  - `git clone git@github.com:your-github-username/private-repo.git`
- Make a superfluous test commit, when you examine the repo in the browser you will see the commit was authored by your work user.name and user.email but pushed to your repository just fine.
- Login to other/enterprise github/gitlab account (probably on a private server but not always) and create a new empty repository without a readme.
- Run `git remote add work git@domain.tld:work-username/repo.git`
- Push to your work repository with `git push -u work`

You can now push/pull from both your work repo and your personal repo. Don't worry about the usernames/emails not matching in the commits -- it honestly doesn't matter.

You can rename your remotes like so:

`git remote rename origin home`

`git remote rename work employer`

You should take care to regularly merge home into work and work into home to reconcile any differences since you shouldnt access work private network from home machine.

*this adds a comment to the key so you can remember what it’s for and also allows you to set an easy to remember name like your GitHub username

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple if you need it for different projects.

You can configure an individual repo to use a specific user / email address which overrides the global configuration. From the root of the repo, run

```
git config user.name "Your Name Here"
git config user.email your@email.com
```

whereas the default user / email is configured in your ~/.gitconfig

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
git config --global user.email your@email.com
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can achieve by doing something like this by using --local instead of --global

**A**
`git config user.email Y`
`git config user.name "X"`

**B**
`git config user.email W`
`git config user.name "Z"`

The values stored in the .git/config for particular repo than the global configuration file.

Comment: does that mean if I have to push to remote **A** I have to do `git config` then do another `git config` before pushing to remote **B**?

Comment: Yes @AbelCallejo this is not an optimal solution.

Answer (score -1):

Say you have an account in `gitlab` with user name `usergitlab` with emails `email@1`, `email@2`, ... And that you also have an account in `github` with user name `usergithub` with emails `email@2`, `email@3`, ...

If your repo has a remote with two different urls, one for `github:org/repo`, another for `gitlab:org/repo`, and your local git email is `email@2`, then the name of the commit's author depends on the name of the user in `gitlab` and in `github`, that is, `usergitlab` and `usergithub` respectively.

Comment: This is not a good answer. It is very common for a person to have a personal repository such as a dotfiles repository that gets pushed to public git{lab,hub}  and also have a remote setup for an enterprise git{lab,hub} server. In such cases you don't want to attach your work email to your personal github account and you can't attach your personal email account to your work account due to security policies. In that case you have a different username and email for each remote because your employer created your work username and email for you.