# How can I "login" to git?

Tags: git, authentication, github, https

I need to change who git thinks I am so I can push to a different repo ( both are mine. ).

Here is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103083/how-do-i-push-to-github-under-a-different-username) but I don't want to set any config variables.

I just want to login once to my current username.  I plan on deleting my other account.

Here is the error when I attempt a `git push origin master`

> remote: Permission to current_user/fav-front.git denied to
>   user_to_delete. fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/current_user/repo.git/': The requested URL
>   returned error: 403

Please note that the git config variables for user and email ( user.name and user.email ) are not related to the authentication that `git push` uses.

They are used for commits.

To reiterate, I want to login to git as current user.

Comment: What about this answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46337214/10871900 You don't need to include the password: `https://user@github.com/username/repo.git`

Comment: Nope.  I saw that.  I simply want to login to git like I did with the old account.  After this single login git will remember that username / password and I won't have to fiddle with it any more.

Comment: If you want to do it only once, you can do `git push https://user@github.com/username/repo.git master`

Comment: I want git to think/know that I am user_new and not user_old.

Comment: Do you want git to think that only for one push or one commit or forever(in that repo)?

Comment: I had to login through bash before as it prompted me to ... is this impossible to ever do again or something?

Comment: Commits are not even involved as they are local operations.  I want git to think this for all my pushes as I mentioned I am deleting my older account.

Comment: Do you mean that git saved your credentials and you want to undo it?

Comment: That appears to be what happened but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is your credential helper?

Comment: I feel like I'm asking how to build a spaceship.  I just want to login to git.  Git must be black magic as I have seen no Google hit on how to do something like `git login`

Comment: I don't know what that is.  I never installed a credential helper.

Comment: I'm not using SSH ... I'm using https ... how the fuck does git know who I am.  Who stored my credentials is a good question.

Comment: Found this ... https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git

Comment: I never did this unless a monkey got on my machine and did it for me when I wasn't looking.

Comment: Found this ...https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain

Comment: The keychain app has my username and password.  That should be illegal.  I never gave it permission or set it up.

Comment: What is a config?

Comment: I had internet problems and I didn't see a few comments. It was about finding out that with keychain.

Comment: And configs are configurations for git(for your repository, your user or your pc)

Comment: @user11623870 Yes, I feel its hard time we have something like `git login` or atleast `github login` !

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar You do have that, for some repository hosting services. I have [edited my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573696/6309) accordingly.

Comment: @VonC That's impressive (although the cli guided setup was little awkward).  And yes, I had to install the [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/). Take my upvote.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't login to Git.

You do login to a Git repository hosting *server*, which requests an authentication, but Git itself has no authentication nor authorization.

(As an example of a Git repository hosting service offering login:

- GitHub: [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)
- GitLab: [`glab auth login`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/main/docs/source/auth/login.md))

What Git does have is credential *caching* (check the output of `git config credential helper`)
On Mac: "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)": you can check if your old user was stored there, and update it.

If you really want to [disable the credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052884/6309), you will be asked your credentials every time you push to a repository hosted on a server requesting authentication.

---

Regarding [AgilePro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1758051/agilepro)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78023117/6309):

> Again, there is no way to ask git to log in, instead you have to make a bogus change and then try to push the change to get it to prompt you to log in.

Not true.

Git itself does not log you in, as mentioned in my answer above.

A third-party CLI tool (like [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/manual/)) can connect to a repository hosting service (like `github.com`) and trigger the authentication.
No repository needed.

With GitHub: create first through the Web UI a [Personal access tokens (classic)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#personal-access-tokens-classic), with minimum required scopes: `repo`, `read:org`, and `gist`.
Its [token prefix](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/#identifiable-prefixes) will be `ghp_...`.

Then authenticate yourself from the command-line, after [installing `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli?tab=readme-ov-file#installation), using [gh auth login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)

```
gh auth login
```

You can enter your GitHub user account name, and your token.

Then, a `gh auth status` would give you:

```bash
C:\Users\vonc\git>gh auth status
github.com
  ✓ Logged in to github.com as VonC (C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Roaming\GitHub CLI\hosts.yml)
  ✓ Git operations for github.com configured to use https protocol.
  ✓ Token: ghp_************************************
  ✓ Token scopes: admin:org, gist, repo, user, workflow
```

You are authenticated (to GitHub, not to "Git").

---

You can also [register your token with the local credential manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/6309):

```bash
git config --global credential.helper manager
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\nusername=<me>\npassword=<my_token>" |\
  git-credential-manager store
```

This is purely for safekeeping, and does not authenticate you.

Comment: How did keychain get my permission to save my username and password?

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi It prompted for them once, then cache them there.

Comment: I know but it never asked me.  It, git, prompted for them once cached them and locked it down like a f****** rabbit hole and stole 2 hours of my life.

Comment: This is the credential input from keychain and not from git.

Comment: @VonC - I just deleted it from the keychain.  This prompted git to ask for username and password.

Comment: After re logging in,  it put it back in the keychain as the correct user.   Is this default behavior for the keychain app?

Comment: @dan1st Right, I have deleted the comment

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi Yes, because of `git config credential.helper`: it is Git which does instruct the keychain to store your credentials, not the keychain itself.

Comment: Well I never touched this thing ... I need to read the docs on git config credential.helper ... I have been traumatized by the keychain app.  I am going to sue Apple for emotional distress :)

Comment: Trick is to just delete the entry and this will force it to ask you to login again.  What I want to know, IS THIS DEFAULT BEHAVIOR?

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi It is the default behavior to ask (Git or not: if the remote URL demans an authentication, it will ask for it), but the storing part is the result of the credential helper. You can disable it with `git config --global --unset credential.helper`

Comment: So the credential helper, in this case, keychain, is set to this behavior by default?

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi the keychain is set to this behavior by Git. The keychain alone would not register anything unless explicitly instructed to do so. Here, Git instructs the keychain to do so because of the credential.helper settings.

Comment: Yea, I know, I got that, a while back.  But what is the default setting for git, is it set to do this by default if I say do a fresh git install ( all default behavior ).  Will test tomorrow unless you know.

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi it should not be set by default, but the result of a manual configuration: https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git

Comment: I find it a bit creepy that it does this be default, kind of like a web app remembering you logged in with out asking.  Guess that is the standard now.  There used to be "remember login" box you checked when logging in but not any more.

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi I am not sure about the "default" part, as I believe you still need to configure Git to trigger that credential caching. But yes, that can be unsettling.

Comment: the client DOES prompt you to log in and it DOES fail to log you in. This answer is not helpful.

the instructions about credential helper yield `error: key does not contain a section: credential`

Comment: @AgilePro Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer to clarify this process.

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem with Windows. Updating Credentials Manager helped in my case.

To open `Credentials Manager` search that setting or navigate to:
`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`. In *Windows Credentials* -> *Generic Credentials* find your repo and update username/password or delete all that are not needed.

Answer (score 4):

**Identify yourself to Git**

In case someone was searching for a "different answer" ;), see
https://jr0cket.co.uk/git-workshop/identify-yourself-to-git.html

in short it's:

> ```
> git config --global user.name "your name"
> git config --global user.email "your.name@domain.com"
> ```
>
> To check what has already been added to Git (some gui clients add
> information), you can list all the current configuration entries:
>
> ```
> git config --list
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If after `git push` to a GitHub repo Git suddenly starts demanding that you login to the remote server, showing you the login prompt, thus:

```
Password for 'https://<OLD_GITHUB_TOKEN>@github.com':
```

it usually means that your GitHub token has expired. You can visit your GitHub repo page, generate a new token (`Settings > Developer settings > Personal access tokens`) and then change it in your local git repo `config` file (e.g. `$ nano <GIT_REPO>/.git/config`), by swapping the token in the `url` entry in the `[remote "origin"]` section:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://<OLD_GITHUB_TOKEN>@github.com/<GIT_USER>/<GIT_REPO>.git

->

[remote "origin"]
    url = https://<NEW_GITHUB_TOKEN>@github.com/<GIT_USER>/<GIT_REPO>.git
```

Comment: Another way to store the token is by running `git config --global credential.helper store` then doing authentication step once (by, for example, `git pull` then inputting the token). It's stored for later use

Answer (score 0):

I installed [GitHub Pull Requests and Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) extension in VS Code then tried to clone a private repo, it asked for browser authentication then it got git connected with my github profile

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to log in and make the git client work.  i could log in to GitHub the site just fine.  I pulled a repository just fine.  But when I committed and wanted to push changes, I needed to be authenticated.

First a Ui pops up, asking for username and password.  I enter them, and that does not work.  it then prompts on the command line for username and then password.  i enter the correct values and that does not work.

You have to **Generate A Token** and use that instead of the password.

So I generated a token, but even that does NOT work in the pop-up UI login prompt.  No idea why it displays that since it has never ever worked for me.  On the command line I was able to enter my user name and the newly generated token and FINALLY I got logged in.

The problem is simply a poor user interface with confusing and inaccurate prompts.  Just imagine how much more accurate and much easier it would be if it said "token" instead of "password".  Crazy.

The token is available only for a moment to copy, so be sure to set up all your repositories while you have it in the cut/paste buffer.  Again, there is no way to ask git to log in, instead you have to make a bogus change and then try to push the change to get it to prompt you to log in.   I would much prefer a comment "login" so that I could do this without necessarily making a change.