# Two github accounts to push to same repo

Tags: git, github

So this is a very specific use case. It would be great if any GitHub gurus can help me.

In my Linux laptop, I want to push to **same** GitHub repo using two different GitHub usernames.

I have setup both the SSH keys in my local machine. I have been able to configure it up until being able to switch between users when committing. This works fine and I can switch between the two configured users while committing.

However whenever I do `git push` I am never able to switch users and it always uses my first username.

Is there a way I can switch or select user when I push to github?

Comment: `I have setup both the SSH keys in my local machine` have you set the certificates up on the local machine *or the same account?* on that machine? If you used different accounts you wouldn't have any problems. Right now you have two different certificates installed for the same remote server on the same account.

Comment: I do not know how to set up the certificates for different account, I guess. If you know, will you write that as an answer,@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain)

Comment: @NilsWerner this link looks useful, I will check it out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

paraphrasing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927828/86072) :

You can create two different hostnames in your `~/.ssh/config`.
For example, if your configuration looks like this:

```
Host github-as-alice
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/id_ed25519.alice
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github-as-bob
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/id_dsa.bob
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then you just use `github-as-alice` and `github-as-bob` instead of the hostname in your URL:

```
git clone github-as-alice:name/whatever.git
cd whatever
git remote add bob github-as-bob:name/whatever.git
```

note: you can also have a "by default" key for github by simply mentioning it in a `Host github.com` section :

```
Host github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/id_ed25519.github
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is use a different username, then you could set the username in the config right before you push each time:

```
$ git config user.name "other_username"
$ git config user.email "other_username"
$ git push
```

Notice that git uses your username when you `commit`, so you would have to change the username before you commit and then push as this user.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103083/how-do-i-push-to-github-under-a-different-username).

Comment: The usernames have nothing to do with pushing but only with committing.

Comment: so is there a way @NilsWerner