# How to push one single local git repo to two different github accounts

Tags: git, github, ssh

Before you jump to flag this as duplicate question, please note:

This other question seems related, but I believe it is not exactly the same and the only answer posted is completely insufficient. I tried Shell Code's solution, but could not make it work:
[Two github accounts to push to same repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989473/two-github-accounts-to-push-to-same-repo)

This other question has a similar title (the result of misleading edition by @derek-brown), but the question is actually completly different from mine:
[Pushing a local repo to multiple github accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129710/pushing-a-local-repo-to-multiple-github-accounts)

---

This is the scenario:

- Windows 10 machine using VS Code, Git Bash and CMD.
- One single repo at C:\code\myproject\.git
- Github account #1 with username github-user1 (email: github-user1@gmail.com)
- Github account #2 with username github-user2 (email: github-user2@gmail.com)
- Github repo #1 under github-user1 at https://github.com/github-user1/myproject
- Github repo #2 under github-user2 at https://github.com/github-user2/myproject

The local repo has the following remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
myremote1 git@github.com:github-user1/myproject.git (fetch)
myremote1 git@github.com:github-user1/myproject.git (push) 
myremote2 git@github.com:github-user2/myproject.git (fetch)
myremote2 git@github.com:github-user2/myproject.git (push)
```

I want to be able to push/pull this repo to both remotes at will in the simplest possible way.

I have so far done the following:

1. Created ssh keys for both identities:

   - id_ed25519_github_user1 for github-user1@gmail.com
   - id_ed25519_github_user2 for github-user2@gmail.com
2. Added the identities to the ssh agent with:

> ```
> $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_user1
> $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_user1
> ```

3. Added the public keys to the SSH Keys section of the corresponding github account, as explained here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account
4. Added a config file in my ~.ssh folder with the following content:

> ```
> #github-user1 account
> Host github-user1
>   Hostname github.com
>   User git
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_user1
>
> #github-user2 account
> Host github-user2
>   Hostname github.com
>   User git
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_user2
> ```

When I try to push to either remote I get an error like this:

```
$ git push myremote1 main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.      

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got it to work by changing the remotes.

[**Edition for clarity**: I am modifying the local users declared in the .ssh/config, so that they are not the same as the github users, as they do not have to be identical in general]

Consider the following updated .ssh/config file:

```
#github-user1 account
Host local-user1
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_user1

#github-user2 account
Host local-user2
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_user2
```

Then the remotes are changed from:

```
$ git remote -v
myremote1 git@github.com:github-user1/myproject.git (fetch)
myremote1 git@github.com:github-user1/myproject.git (push) 
myremote2 git@github.com:github-user2/myproject.git (fetch)
myremote2 git@github.com:github-user2/myproject.git (push)
```

To:

```
$ git remote -v
myremote1 git@local-user1:github-user1/myproject.git (fetch)
myremote1 git@local-user1:github-user1/myproject.git (push) 
myremote2 git@local-user2:github-user2/myproject.git (fetch)
myremote2 git@local-user2:github-user2/myproject.git (push)
```

Please note I have changed the hostnames after the "@" to the ones I had entered in the config file in the ~.ssh folder.

That is the solution that has worked for me.

However, as pointed out by the respected @VonC, the `git@` part is not necessary in the remotes, because git is already specified in the `~/.ssh/config` file, as `User git`. Therefore, I understand they could be as follows:

```
$ git remote -v
myremote1 local-user1:github-user1/myproject.git (fetch)
myremote1 local-user1:github-user1/myproject.git (push) 
myremote2 local-user2:github-user2/myproject.git (fetch)
myremote2 local-user2:github-user2/myproject.git (push)
```

I have not tested this, but I trust it will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

The actual command to use are:

```bash
cd /path/to/repository
git remote set-url myremote1 github-user1:github-user1/myproject.git
git remote set-url myremote2 github-user2:github-user2/myproject.git
```

You do not need the `git@` part, since it is already specified in the `~/.ssh/config` file, as `User git`.

Comment: Thank you @VonC. Please note you have typed "...:github-user1/..." on both lines. Is that intentional?

Comment: @freenrg Good point, that was a typo. I have edited the answer accordingly.