# How to use `git push` with a username/token combination just for this one push?

Tags: git

I have access to a github repo, but when I do

```
git push
```

I get the error

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I add a specific username/token combination to this very `git push` (without changing the ""default"" settings)?

I did not find any option to set the credentials for the `git push` command.

I had a look at the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103083/how-do-i-push-to-github-under-a-different-username) but none of the confusing solution seem to work. I still get the exact same error message when I do `git push`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push to GitHub under a different username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103083/how-do-i-push-to-github-under-a-different-username)

Comment: The answers in that question do not seem to work

Comment: looks like the topikstarter is asking something else..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found a solution, which only works if the repository you want to push to is public.

1. You open the public repo of the other user2 in a web page where you are logged in as user1
2. You create a fork of the repo from user2 to your user1 "space".
3. You clone that forked repo as user1.
4. You make the changes, add/commit and push it back to the forked repo of user1.
5. You create a pull request to the repo of user2.
6. In a browser where you are logged in as user2 you merge the merge request.